# Visual Studio 2017 Python "KeyError: 'BREAK_SYSTEMEXIT_ZERO' "

Tags: python, python-2.7, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2017

I use Visual Studio 2017. When I try to debug python code like this:

```
     print " hello "
```

I get this error :

---

```
warning: Debugger speedups using cython not found. Run '"C:\Program Files\Python37\python.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python\Core\Packages\ptvsd\pydevd\setup_cython.py" build_ext --inplace' to build.
pydev debugger: starting

Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python\Core\Packages\ptvsd\wrapper.py", line 796, in done
    fut.result() 
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python\Core\Packages\ptvsd\futures.py", line 40, in result
    reraise(self._exc_info)   
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python\Core\Packages\ptvsd\reraise3.py", line 8, in reraise
    raise exc_info[1].with_traceback(exc_info[2]) 
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python\Core\Packages\ptvsd\futures.py", line 149, in callback
    x = next(it)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python\Core\Packages\ptvsd\wrapper.py", line 1004, in on_launch
    args.get('options', options))
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Python\Core\Packages\ptvsd\wrapper.py", line 959, in _parse_debug_options
  options[key] = DEBUG_OPTIONS_PARSER[key](value)
KeyError: 'BREAK_SYSTEMEXIT_ZERO'
```

Comment: @madjaoue i expect to desplay '' hi '' but the error show up

Comment: Might be similar to this https://github.com/Microsoft/PTVS/issues/888

Comment: @Khalil Sebti, You could learn the python here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/tutorial-working-with-python-in-visual-studio-step-02-writing-code, the correct code is print("hello")